# How to change exception language in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, exception

I'm facing some quite a problem that the exception throwing should be in difference language than English (is French now, but maybe next time Portugese?).

That I tried changing the culture info right before when the exception being throw, but still got English as result.

This is the code

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");

using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var shouldThrowExceptionHere = await httpClient.GetAsync("ShouldThrowExceptionHere");
```

I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.
>
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.PrepareRequestMessage(HttpRequestMessage request)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.CheckRequestBeforeSend(HttpRequestMessage request)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

The url was invalid since the first place, so the exception is not throwing from some other thread.

As deep as I can drill down is that the exception throwing make use of pre-processed shared resource which already compile (before runtime), that causing fixed string took out.

Is there anyway that I could achieve this requirement in ASP.NET Core, version 3.1 or greater would be nice.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the first place? Exceptions shouldn't be shown to end users. The exception language depends on the *runtime* language, not the application language. While you could add a language pack to localize them, this will guarantee developers won't be able to google error messages

Comment: Said another way, trap the exception and return your own custom exception that is localized as needed.

Comment: @DavidL Why throw a custom exception? Exceptions shouldn't be shown to end users.

Comment: @mason, no, _stacktraces_ shouldn't be shown to end users.  The entire reason why exception filter middleware exists is to repackage exceptions so that they CAN be shown to end users.

Comment: @DavidL I completely disagree. Error messages in exceptions can also reveal sensitive information, not just stack traces. And if you were to throw a custom exception, you would most likely set the inner exception to be the original one, so you're really not hiding anything. Exceptions shouldn't be used as part of normal application flow. If something went wrong, catch the exception then log it, then return some sort of error result with a user friendly error message. That error result can be localized as appropriate, but exceptions are purely for developers.

Comment: @mason agree to disagree. This requires you to use result objects throughout your entire stack which obfuscates intent. This is not a hard and fast rule (despite your objection) and shops will take different approaches.  That said, there is a reasonable amount of MS documentation that suggests using localized messages in exceptions specifically for users: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions#include-a-localized-string-message-in-every-exception and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.message?view=net-5.0#remarks

Comment: Just a side note... I'm completely want to get the English exception message, but some other in my team agreed to put this on. So... I just have to choice, since they doesn't listen in the first place. But I will fulfill the requirement, regarding that could be done or not. Thank for your help guys, really appreciate.

Comment: @DavidL Btw... I just take a look on your link, but that's all about the custom application resource which I currently using for multi-language, but that's not working on the exception case... do you have some other doc related to this ?

Comment: @GordonKhanhNg I'm not aware of a way for you to force internal libraries to use your localizations if they do not provide them, and I can't find any documentation that says that they do.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The language pack really worked on .Net Framework, but currently, our project is based on .Net Core. I just come across MS sdk and runtime download page, tried finding the language pack... but seems like i couldn't found one... could you give out a link or some hint that I could follow ? Thanks for reading.

Comment: @DavidL at least I got some kind of confirmation to pass over people. Thanks again and have a good day :D